# SUM of Specific Duplicates in a long list of duplicates

Tags: excel, duplicates

I want to sum specific duplicates from a column. in fact, I have 7 columns of people names(About 1,000 names in each column but they all repeat between 10-180 times). I have a list of 25 specific people that I need to find how many times their names have repeated into that particular column and I don’t need the sum of the remaining names. I guess once I have the formula to apply for one column, I should be able to copy paste it on the columns where I need my answers.

Can i have some help in applying an appropriate formula please? I tried sumif but is coming back as an error.

Comment: Enter countif in the search box above.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the `COUNTIF` function.

```
  | A      | B      | C      | D | E              | F     |
1 | Names 1| Names 2| Names 3|   | Names to Count | Count |
  |--------|--------|--------|   |----------------|-------|
2 | Alice  | Bob    | Malcom |   | Alice          |  4    |
3 | Alice  | Alice  | Malcom |   | Bob            |  6    |
4 | Malcom | Bob    | Bob    |   | Total          | 10    |
5 | Bob    | Malcom | Bob    |
6 | Alice  | Malcom | Bob    |
```

To do the counting use the following function:

```
=COUNTIF(table, name) // Where table is your table of names,
                      // and name is the name to count.

// In my example this would be as follows:
=COUNTIF($A$2:$C$6; E2) // for Alice
=COUNTIF($A$2:$C$6; E3) // for Bob
=SUM(F2:F3)             // for total
```